# What is the meaning of term 'leg' in freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

I am beginner to freeswitch.While learning this I have seen the terms 'leg A' and 'leg B'.
I didn't understand about this.So please explain me about this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has some nice information as well:
https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Call%20Legs

-MC

Answer (score 3):

Leg is a connection (between equipments).  In a network diagram, a connection look like a leg.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the FreeSwitch DialPlan tools like transfer or blind transfer user notions of 
leg A - as a person who dialed (caller)
log B - as a person who was dialed (callee)

As a good example is [bind_meta_app](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Misc._Dialplan_Tools_bind_meta_app)

So for example you can execute some command or do an action if a key was pressed by (caller (leg) **a** or callee (leg) **b** or any leg in this case caller or callee **ab**)